# How to select the row in pandas based on a list?

Tags: python, pandas

here is the case need to ask your advice.

I have a dataframe as below by using line

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,400,10).reshape(10, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df
```

[image]

Then, I have a list as following:

```
array([ 331,  51, 131, 211])
```

I would like to get a table with column B only contains the values stated in the list. 
For instance, I generate the expected output manually as below:

[image]

Thank you for your advice in advance. Thanks!

Comment: `df[df['B'].isin(your_list)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it with the isin function of pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

```
df[df["B"].isin(yourarray.tolist())]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your answer has helped me! I just realize it can be done with just a single line, that is awesome!